# crawl 1000 url per recrawl in nutch

Tags: nutch

hello
 i wrote an crawl script to crawl the url and i need to fetch 1000 urls per crawl session if i use this 
`bin/nutch fetch $s1 -threads 100 -topN 1000`
it crawls more than 1000 url i have no idea y it happens can any one tell me how can i crawl exactly 1000 urls per crawl session in nutch1.2

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head you should use

```
bin/nutch generate ... -topN 1000
```

Fetch only uses the result of generate.